# Given a system of differential equations, how can one tell if $\textbf{x}_c = (0,0)^T$ is a unique critical point?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have: 
$$\frac{d\textbf{x}}{dt}=\begin{bmatrix}
    -1       & 2 \\
    -2       & -1  \\
\end{bmatrix}\textbf{x}(t)$$ with $\textbf{x}(0)=(1,-1)^T$.

I am asked whether the critical point $\textbf{x}_c=(0,0)^T$ is unique or not. 
I don't know how to go about answering this one.. Help please! :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The critical point(s) occur where

$\dfrac{d\mathbf x}{dt} = 0; \tag{1}$

since, as a *vector field*,

$\dfrac{d\textbf{x}}{dt}=\begin{bmatrix}
    -1       & 2 \\
    -2       & -1  \\
\end{bmatrix}\textbf{x}, \tag{2}$

the critical points occur wherever

$\begin{bmatrix}
    -1       & 2 \\
    -2       & -1  \\
\end{bmatrix}\textbf{x}_c = 0 \tag{3}$

has a solution.  We see that

$\det(\begin{bmatrix}
    -1       & 2 \\
    -2       & -1  \\
\end{bmatrix}) = 5 \ne 0; \tag{4}$

the coefficient matrix is thus non-singular; the only solution to (3) is

$\mathbf x_c = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}; \tag{5}$

thus this critical point is indeed unique.

Comment: That's it?? Okay, thank you!

Comment: That's it.   Glad to help out.  Cheers!

Comment: I looked at your website. You seem like an interesting dude.

Comment: Heh!  Thanks, I'd like to think so . . . by the way, not to put too fine a point on it, you can always upvote/accept my answer if you like it . . . or not!  Forgive me for saying this, but you know musicians:  shamelessly self-promoting.  Anyway, do what you feel . . . more Cheers!

Comment: So shameless! I'm aghast. Fellow musician, I understand! 
Plus it was a top-notch answer, of course!

Comment: Hey, another musician, awesome!  Thanks for the understanding, musician to musician, and of course, the "acceptance"!  What do you play?  What instruments, what kind of music?

Comment: I'm good at guitar, acceptable at banjo, and dabble in just about anything else. Mostly my voice is my favorite instrument though! Right now I've been playing a lot of Van Morrison. After you stop hating the guy, you learn to love him!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23057/discussion-between-bliebervik-and-robert-lewis).